# What is the best way to stop two rules redirecting endlessly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm setting up a local apache server using XAMPP for use with CodeIgniter. My background is primarily in PHP and I have not had much experience with configuring apache or writing .htaccess files.

I am trying to remove the need for `/index.php` in the URL and redirect away from URLs that contain `/index.php` to the URL that doesn't.

However, when I run the two rules I have wrote to achieve this the page endlessly redirects. Individually they work as intended.

```
# Remove /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [L,R=301,QSA]

# Remap addresses to go to index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Ultimately it should redirect from:

`http://localhost/index.php/dashboard/example/`

to

`http://localhost/dashboard/example/`

Which it does but it endless redirects afterwards.

Comment: You can try to add `END` tou your second rule: `[L,END,QSA]` ([Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end))

Comment: @Kaddath that works for what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `END` flag in the second rule, as per [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end):

> Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like [L]) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing

Beware that it should be set on the last rewriting rule that needs to apply if there are several, because no more rewrite will be done after.